# Joining three tables in solr

Tags: join, solr, cassandra, datastax

I am trying to join three cassandra tables using Solr. According to datastax documentation ,

> DataStax Enterprise 4.0.2 and later supports the OS Solr query time
>   join through a custom implementation. You can join Solr documents,
>   including those having different Solr cores under these conditions:
>
> - Solr cores need to have the same keyspace and same Cassandra    partition key.
> - Both Cassandra tables that support the Solr cores to    be joined have to be either Thrift- or CQL-compatible. You cannot    have one
>     that is Thift-compatible and one that is CQL-compatible.
> - The type of the unique key (Cassandra key validator of the partition key)    are the same.
> - The order of table partition keys and schema unique    keys are the same.

I could join two tables as per the documentation. I was wondering whether I can join three tables together satisfying the conditions. Couldn't find any documentation on joining more than two tables. I desperately need to join three tables. Is it really possible or should I drop the idea right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed was a recursive join. From the same documentation as the above example, I could find this example:

```
Use a nested join query to recursively join the songs and lyrics documents with the videos document, and to select the song that mentions love and also won a video award.



 http://localhost:8983/solr/internet.songs/select/?q=
                 {!join+fromIndex=internet.lyrics}words:love AND _query_:
                 {!join+fromIndex=internet.videos}award:true&indent=true&wt=json


Output is:

    "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
        {
          "song":"a3e64f8f-bd44-4f28-b8d9-6938726e34d4",
          "title":"Dangerous",
          "artist":"Big Data"}]
    }}
```